# Use case for non-final static variable

Tags: java, static-members

After a couple of years using Java i've just realized that i don't understand what it the use case for non-final static variables. Can someone give me some hints or any example?

Maybe they are needed to be used in static methods? ... or useful to be shared between all instances?

What concerns me is they can be accessed and modified asynchronously by any subclass, or through any instance.

Thanks.

** note **

Sorry about duplication. I did my search before posting and i didn't find it.

Comment: +1 not because it is a good question, but because you obviously show real interest, and I like to encourage that. BTW: all your assumptions are correct.

Answer (score 0):

As constants they have no use, which I believe is your main trails of thoughts are concentrated around.

But how do you think a static class is going to perform it's operations if there is any need for class scope variables that need to be shared across the method calls?

Or there are instances where data need to be stored in a static class etc.

There are a lot of use cases if you just stop to think about it.

Comment: I'm not convinced - I just ran a search on a project I'm working on and could not find a single occurence... static + mutable is a dangerous combination...

Comment: Only if you don't take the necessary precautions... This is my opinion. But hey I'm willing to change my mind, Just give me a good reason...

Comment: "static + mutable is a dangerous combination" that's my point ... so i don't really see what is their role in Java ... what is the problem they solve.

Comment: @Rafael The problem they solve is if you do want or need a static variable. That you don't see a need does not mean no one else has a need for it.